# How to get insert query of table rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, insert

I have entered a data by using insert query and forget to save the file, and now I want those queries, I don't want to write them again - is there any way to get the insert queries of tables rows in SQL Server?

Would appreciate your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT  dest.text
FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
WHERE dest.text LIKE 'SOMETHING_UNIQUE_ABOUT_YOUR_QUERY%';
```

Comment: can u please explain it? is dest is table name? and what is text?

Comment: It'll try to find the query from a table of sql cached query plans. There is a chance that the plan generated by your lost query is still in the cache. Interesting approach.

Comment: @Salman A please explain more how to get sql cached query plans? i didn't find anything

Comment: I hope you didn't type `SOMETHING_UNIQUE_ABOUT_YOUR_QUERY` as-is.

Comment: yeah, but what to write there?

Comment: my table name is Company and it has 10 records , so now what to write their?

Comment: As @Salman said, we try to look into performance statistics for cached query plans in SQL Server. more info in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).
To me, i would  do like this in the WHERE statement: 
WHERE dest.text LIKE %INSERT INTO%Company%';

Comment: @TimeToCode run this query in SSMS